# Calculations while making dataframe aggregation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a Pandas Dataframe which looks like

```
id     rank     weight

2      4        2
6      12       1
3      9        1
7      1        2
1      4        4
7      3        1
2      19       2
6      3        2
8      4        3
5      7        1
2      5        2
1      6        1
3      1        1
```

I want to calculate SUM of `rank*weight` for each distinct `id` and store it as a new dataframe. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If need only one output column use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.product.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('id')['rank','weight'].sum().product(1))
print (df1.reset_index(name='out'))
   id  out
0   1   50
1   2  168
2   3   20
3   5    7
4   6   45
5   7   12
6   8   12
```